# Better Match, Compare, and Replace Differences method

Tags: vba, excel

So I've been working on this sheet on and off for a couple weeks now.  I feel like I've gotten very close to completion.  It does everything that my customer wants it to do.  My new struggle though is that when I populate it with the customers real data.  After initial filtering is about 30,000 rows and 14 columns.  It is just too much for my method of looking for a match, comparing, and replacing.  What I am doing is pretty obvious.  I search for a match in the first column, then compare the adjacent cells.  If there is a difference, I move the master cell data into a comment and move the update data into the master cell.

It works, don't get me wrong.  I was pretty proud of myself.  But comparing the data is a bit overloading the way I have it.

```
Sub Compare_Function_MatchEval()
        Call Set_Variables
        UpdateSheet.Activate
        For w = 5 To UpdateSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            v = 1
            CellVal = UpdateSheet.Cells(w, 1).Value
            MasterSheet.Activate
            z = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CellVal, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells((Rows.Count), 1)), 0)
            For y = 2 To UpdateSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                v = v + 1
                If Not UpdateSheet.Cells(w, v) = MasterSheet.Cells(z, v) Then
                    OldData = MasterSheet.Cells(z, v)
                    NewData = UpdateSheet.Cells(w, v)
                    MasterSheet.Cells(z, v).AddComment
                    MasterSheet.Cells(z, v).Comment.Text Text:=OldData
                    MasterSheet.Cells(z, v).Comment.Visible = False
                    MasterSheet.Cells(z, v) = NewData
                End If
            Next
        Next
        wbMaster.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        wbMaster.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: That is not VB.NET code.  Please remove the tag.

Comment: 324 Seconds to execute currently :-(

Comment: What's the purpose of the first `WorksheetFunction.Match` call there? you put the result in `x` but I don't see where you use it.

Comment: Dead code.  Its been removed already.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that adding a lot of comments to the spreadsheet is just always going to be slow. If so, you might think about handling that differently, like with a  shadow sheet. If all your cells are  going to end up with comments anyway, you might as well make that comment data easier to get at.

The first `WorksheetFunction.Match` call is dead code, according to your comment, so hopefully your timing results didn't reflect the code as given.

The second (or only) `WorksheetFunction.Match` call re-establishes a search range each time; that Range could set once and used. That would avoid the need for `MasterSheet.Activate` in the loop. You could put this:

```
    Dim SearchZone as Range
        :
        MasterSheet.Activate
        Set SearchZone = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells((Rows.Count), 1))

        For w = 5 To UpdateSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            v = 1
            CellVal = UpdateSheet.Cells(w, 1).Value
            z = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CellVal, SearchZone, 0)
            :
```

It would be worth testing how the execution time is split between the Match and the updates. If the Match is slow then pulling off the keys (for Master and Update) and sorting them, then simply traversing, might be better. For economy of coding you could let Excel do the key sorting work in a temporary sheet.

I assume the Set_Variables call is turning off ScreenUpdating.

Comment: How would you call it once so that finds an array of data, and returns the row in which it finds said array?

Comment: @Addohm added example of how to do this - if I understood your question (not sure :-) )

Answer (score 0):

**edited**; since variant arrays are 1-based

**edited 2**: tested, and to earn some seconds more, stored `UBound(updateShtArr, 1)` and `UBound(updateShtArr, 2)` into variables

Use arrays to max extent (not possible with comments)

the code should be a follows (tested):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare_Function_MatchEval()

    Call Set_Variables
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    updateShtArr = UpdateSheet.UsedRange.Value
    masterShtArr = MasterSheet.UsedRange.Value

    iUp1Max = UBound(updateShtArr, 1)
    iUp2Max = UBound(updateShtArr, 2)
    For w = 5 To iUp1Max
        z = GetRow(masterShtArr, iUp1Max, updateShtArr(w, 1))
        If z >= 0 Then
            For v = 2 To iUp2Max
                If Not updateShtArr(w, v) = masterShtArr(z, v) Then
                    With MasterSheet.Cells(z, v)
                      .AddComment
                      .Comment.Text Text:=masterShtArr(z, v)
                      .Comment.Visible = False
                      .Value = updateShtArr(w, v)
                    End With
                End If
             Next v
         End If
    Next w

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Function GetRow(arr As Variant, iMax, val As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    GetRow = -1
    For i = 1 To iMax
        If arr(i, 1) = val Then
            GetRow = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Did you simulate this with a similar volume of comparisons?  What were your times like?  I will give this a go tomorrow.

Comment: I've repeatedly tested my code and as comments increase, the speed is excessively dampered.  I may just create another sheet that shows changed values instead of using comments.  Keep in mind though I haven't tested your code yet.

Comment: I tested with some 40k rows x 14 columns and it took some 90 secs. And with a few comments. But of course it's also up to the machine and other stuff

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if a VS add-in or application is more appropriate for this.  Once I land and check into my hotel, I'm going to work on your code.  I quickly added it to test last night and it was still very slow and it wasn't commenting the correct cells.  I probably bothered it somehow as I was in a rush.